# C# WPF Pause processing until button has been pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, wait

I decided to create my own dialog windows in WPF. I have it working using a Frame and navigating to a WPF page in the frame to get the appropriate dialog window I previously made. The problem comes when trying to return a value. For example if I have 'ok' and 'cancel' I would want to return a Boolean value upon pressing 'ok' or 'cancel' on the page displayed in the frame.

```
//This is what I'm using to display the dialog window frame.
public bool DisplayQuestion(string subject, string message)
    {
        AlertIsUp = true;
        var questionPage = new QuestionPage(AlertFrame, subject, message);
        AlertFrame.Navigate(questionPage);
        if (MainFrame.Content != null && MainFrame.Content.ToString() == "System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser")
        {
            MainFrame.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        //I need it to wait until a button on the dialog frame is pressed before continuing.
        return QuestionResponse;
    }
```

What happens is that is will immediately return the Boolean value which of course is always false. I need it to wait until 'ok' or 'cancel' are pressed within the page and then continue on to return it's value.

Here is the code within the page.

```
Frame AlertFrame { get; set; }
public bool AlertIsUp { get; set; }
public bool QuestionResponse { get; set; }

public QuestionPage(Frame alertFrame, string subject, string message)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    theMesssage.Content = message;
    subjectLabel.Content = subject;
    AlertFrame = alertFrame;
    AlertIsUp = MainWindow.AlertIsUp;
    QuestionResponse = MainWindow.QuestionResponse;

}

private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AlertFrame.Content = null;
    AlertIsUp = false;
    QuestionResponse = false;
}

private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AlertFrame.Content = null;
    AlertIsUp = false;
    QuestionResponse = true;
}
```

Of course if I just add While(AlertIsUp) then if freezes the GUI.
It is very possible that I am doing things backward since I have not taken any formal training in C#. Thank you for your kind responses to my first post on this site.

Comment: Since everything else I have completed is already built around pages it just fell into place. I really like the way it fits in with the rest of the stylized GUI. This is really the only roadblock I have hit. Of course if this can't be done then I may have to look into getting something close enough using a modal dialog solution, but I can't imagine this not being possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found a solution to this problem here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36516/WPF-Modal-Dialog

The solution ended up placing this short piece of code:

```
while (AlertIsActive)
    {
        if (this.Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted ||
            this.Dispatcher.HasShutdownFinished)
        {
            break;
        }

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `delegate` in your dialog `Window` and attach a handler from the same method that creates and shows it. Then you can call the delegate when the `Button` is clicked and the launching class will get called. You'll then know the value and be able to close the `Window`.

If you don't know about `delegate`s then you should definitely read the [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173171.aspx) page on MSDN to help you understand this solution. You could do something like this:

In your dialog `Window`:

```
public void delegate Response(bool response);

public Response OnButtonClick { get; set; }
```

Then in the code that launches the dialog `Window`:

```
DialogWindow dialogWindow = new DialogWindow();
dialogWindow.OnButtonClick += OnButtonClick;
dialogWindow.Show();
```

...

```
public void OnButtonClick(bool response)
{
    if (response) { /* Ok */ }
    else { /* Cancel */ }
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Apologies for forgetting to show you the crucial part. When the `Button` is clicked, the dialog `Window` calls the `delegate`:

```
private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AlertFrame.Content = null;
    AlertIsUp = false;
    QuestionResponse = false;
    if (OnButtonClick != null) OnButtonClick(QuestionResponse);
}

private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AlertFrame.Content = null;
    AlertIsUp = false;
    QuestionResponse = true;
    if (OnButtonClick != null) OnButtonClick(QuestionResponse);
}
```

Of course, you won't really have much need for your `QuestionResponse` property and you could just as easily return `true` or `false` in the `QuestionResponse delegate`. Once that is called, the handler will get the response.

Regarding your comment about you not using different `Window`s, it makes little difference with `delegate`s, it will work just the same. You can use them when there's no UI involved at all.

Comment: Thank you for the response, although I'm not sure it applies. This is not using DialogWindow, separate windows are not being used. All of this is within one window with a Frame navigating to a WPF Page for the dialog. The answer may be in a delegate somehow though. I will read though the information you provided to see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to show you the crucial part... I'll edit it now.